# Playwright: Executing different test suites depending on script parameter

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, playwright

I have switched to Playwright recently and I would like to ask you for some feedback on my current issue which I am facing at the moment.

I have a simple framework set up for one of our company applications. Inside the framework there is a folder structure for Page Object Models with their Components and tests have their own structure. Automated tests are divided  into Smoke Test Suite folder and Regression Test Suite folder. I have created a simple "Test" script so it allows to me execute all automated test cases. However I would like to know if there is a way of setting up the script configuration so when I type in console for example `npm Test Smoke Suite` or `npm Test Regression Suite` only of will be executed.

Regards and thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on what exactly you use. Playwright could be used with jest, mocha, ...

Some examples with mocha:

**package.json**:

```
"scripts": {
    "smoke-test": "mocha tests/smoke-tests",
    "regression-test": "mocha tests/regression-tests"
}
```

then you'd run e.g. `$ npm run smoke-test` and only tests in `./tests/smoke-tests` directory will be executed. Make sure you don't override this setting in e.g. `.mocharc.json` (`spec` parameter).

Or you can "tag" tests:

```
test('Open homepage @retired', async function () {
    // some tests steps
});
```

and execute all tests without a tag:

**package.json**:

```
"scripts": {
    "test-not-retired": "mocha -i --grep @retired"
}
```

There're probably more options how to select only a subset of tests to run.

Another way of setting this up is in e.g. `.mocharc.json` as I hinted at above.

---

Jest will have similar options, I'm sure. I'll leave you to it, you can search on the internet as well and experiment a bit.

Of course, if you use a different set-up, my answer could not apply easily. In that case, you'd need to be more specific in your question.

Comment: Cheers for the answer and yes you are right. I forgot that to add that I am using Mocha as a test runner, I will know better next time. It is good to know that such solution is possible for my current set up.

Comment: Forgot to add in previous comment. What did you mean by .mocharc.json example? Is it a file inside a mocha lib that you can configure as well? Cheers!

Comment: Please see the docs: https://mochajs.org/#-config-path => https://mochajs.org/#configuring-mocha-nodejs You have more options, not only .mocharc.json, that's just what I use.